# Optimize creation of dictionary

Tags: python, optimization

I have a list with ids called `ids`. Every element in `ids` is a string. One `id` can exist multiple times in this list.

My aim is to create a dictionary which has the the number of occurrences as a key and the value is a list of the ids which appear that often.
My current approach looks like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
ids = ["foo", "foo", "bar", "hi", "hi"]
counts = defaultdict(list)
for id in np.unique(ids):
    counts[ids.count(id)].append(id)
```

Output:

```
print counts
--> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['bar'], 2: ['foo', 'hi']})
```

This works nicely if the list of ids is not too long. However, for longer lists the performance is rather bad.

How can I make this faster?

Comment: Do you really need NumPy for that? You could've used `for id in set(ids)` instead. Also, you're doing almost the same as `collections.Counter`, maybe you could look into that for ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `count` for each element in the list, create a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for the entire list:

```
ids = ["foo", "foo", "bar", "hi", "hi"]
counts = defaultdict(list)
for i, c in Counter(ids).items():
    counts[c].append(i)
# counts: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['bar'], 2: ['foo', 'hi']})
```

---

If you prefer a one-liner, you could also combine  [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) (for view on the elements sorted by counts) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (but I rather wouldn't)

```
>>> {k: [v[0] for v in g] for k, g in groupby(Counter(ids).most_common(), lambda x: x[1])}
{1: ['bar'], 2: ['foo', 'hi']}
```